# react native fetch called only 1 time

Tags: react-native

I'm developing a react-native app,
at this point I register the user with firebase.auth and then send the data also to an external sql database, the problem is that when the API fetch is called the first time it works perfectly, but from the second onwards the data is not sent, without returning any type of reply.
If I uninstall and reinstall the app the same thing happens (fecth only works on the first try). Some idea?note: the "console.log ('2')" command is called only the first time.
here is my code:

````
            .auth()
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
            .then((user)=>{
              var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;              
                  // User is signed in

                  user.sendEmailVerification() //this always work
                  fetch('https://url/application/adduser.php?info1=test&info2='+firebase.auth().currentUser.email+'&info3='+firebase.auth().currentUser.uid, {headers: {
                    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate',
                    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
                    'Expires': 0
                  }})

            .then(() => {
              console.log("2")
            }).catch((error) => {
              console.error(error)
             })
                     .then(function() {

                          navigate('confermaReg')             
                  }, function(error) {
                      // An error happened.
                      let errorCode = error.code
                      let errorMessage = error.message;
                        this.onLoginFailure.bind(this)(errorMessage)
                  })



            })
            .catch((error) => {
              let errorCode = error.code
              let errorMessage = error.message;
                this.onLoginFailure.bind(this)(errorMessage)
            });
          ```
````

Answer (score 0):

That is because once the user is created in firebase, The firebase keeps the user logged in and does not creates next time unless you logout and create another user. So it seems like your "then" function is being called only once due to this reason.

Comment: The problem is that I run the signout, I also thought it could be the problem, but if I try to register again firebase recognizes and enters the new data in its authenticator database, only the fetch is not performed.
In fact, once I change the page with navigator, I run the command "firebase.auth (). SignOut ();" which takes me back to the login page.